# Doctrine query with LPAD (custom function)

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I need to perform the next query in Doctrine:

```
SELECT MAX(LPAD(SUBSTRING(code, 1, instr(code, '/')-1), 6, '0')) as lastCode
FROM provider
WHERE entry_date >= '%s'", date("Y") . "-01-01"
```

*(in short: I have providers with codes xx/yy where yy is 2 digit year and xx is a sequential number, as this code is varchar I perform a query to get last **numeric** code in this year)*

The problem is the use of `LPAD`. If I use query builder I get an error for using custom functions, if I use native query I get empty results.

Here is my code:

**With native query**:

```
$sqlMaxCode = sprintf("SELECT MAX(LPAD(SUBSTRING(code, 1, instr(code, '/')-1), 6, '0')) as lastCode
    FROM provider
    WHERE entry_date >= '%s'", date("Y") . "-01-01");

$nQuery = $em->createNativeQuery($sqlMaxCode, new ResultSetMapping());
$rows = $nQuery->getSingleResult();
$this->get('logger')->info(print_r($rows, true));
//$rows is always empty
```

**With query builder**:

```
$qb = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Provider')->createQueryBuilder('I');
$qb->select('MAX(LPAD(SUBSTRING(code, 1, instr(code, "/")-1), 6, "0")) as lastCode')
    ->where("I.entryDate >= ?1")
    ->setParameter('1', date("Y") . "-01-01");

$result = $qb->getQuery()->getSingleResult();
```

Query builder throws this error:

> Error: Expected known function, got 'LPAD'

Do I have other choices? Why is native query returning empty result? (same query on mysql console shows last number)

**Note**: I tried `CAST(MAX(SUBSTRING(...) as unsigned)...` but have same problem with `CAST` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had an error in native query, if I configure correctly the `ResultSetMapping` native query can deal with custom functions correctly:

```
$rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
$rsm->addScalarResult('lastCode', 'lastCode');

$sqlMaxCode = sprintf("SELECT MAX(LPAD(SUBSTRING(code, 1, instr(code, '/')-1), 6, '0')) as lastCode
    FROM provider
    WHERE entry_date >= '%s'", date("Y") . "-01-01");

$nQuery = $em->createNativeQuery($sqlMaxCode, $rsm);
$rows = $nQuery->getSingleResult();
$this->get('logger')->info(print_r($rows, true));
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer.